# content wise operation in polars series?

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

i have a dataframe with 2 series, i want to create new column that has 1 if if start word of array one series is equal to start word of another series else 0.
**How do I do it?**
i am using polars, it seems a little complex than pandas.

```
dff = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [[1,3,3,3,], [3,5,3,4], [4,7,5,3]], "bar": [[3,345,3,4], [3,4,334,2], [4,52,4,2]]})
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────┬───────────────┐
│ foo         ┆ bar           │
│ ---         ┆ ---           │
│ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ [1, 3, … 3] ┆ [3, 345, … 4] │
│ [3, 5, … 4] ┆ [3, 4, … 2]   │
│ [4, 7, … 3] ┆ [4, 52, … 2]  │
└─────────────┴───────────────┘
```

`like 'common start': [0,1,1]`